# Desindexar archivos Lamp

Tags: php, lampp, lamp

tengo un leve problema el cual me está dando mucho dolor de cabeza,
tengo un servidor apache2, con lamp en una distro de Debian, el problema es que si accedo
[www.dominio.com/carpeta](http://www.dominio.com/carpeta), veo el contenido de la carpeta.
la cosa es que no quiero verlo, a parte, si yo accedo a un archivo .php dentro de esta el archivo se ejecuta, estos no se deberían de ejecutar si no está el login hecho.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el hecho de ocultar los archivos lo que he echo ha sido insertar un archivo .htaccess con el siguiente contenido

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
```

Para denegar el acceso a los archivos lo que he hecho es comprobar si tienen la cookies de sesión con el usuario, sino esta no funciona la aplicación, pero no creo que sea una buena practica

```
 <?php
//comprobamos que el usuario este logeado
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    


    //aqui ira el codigo


}else{
    //si no esta logeado lo mandamos a la pagina de login
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Y que has intentado para lograr ocultar los directorios ??? y que has intentado hacer para evitar que entrer a un php si no han hecho el Login/Sesionado???

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Ya esta cambiado, podrias quitar el downvote para poder llegar a mas gente y que me puedan ayudar? Gracias

Comment: yo no vote negativo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para evitar el seguimiento de directorio se debe manejar con `.htaccess`:

```
# desabilita la navegacion por directorios
Options -Indexes 
# oculta el contenido de los directorios
IndexIgnore *
#habilita los archivos php
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

En cuanto al control de login como lo estás haciendo está mal; si es de forma procedural puedes utilizar algo como esto:

Cualquier archivo `php`:

```php
include_once(validate.php):

//tu codigo aqui abajo
```

Contenido de `validate.php`:

```php
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}
```

Con esto último estamos validando que si el usuario no está en la sesión debemos redirigir automáticamente al login y salir de esta ejecución actual.

***nota:*** recuerda que cada pagina archivo php debe llevar su inicializador de la session para poder continuar con la validacion de sesiones.